# docker make utility not caching changes

Tags: docker, gnu-make

I am using `make` utility inside a docker container. The files I am working with are inside a volume connected to my windows host.

Every time I run make, it rebuilds files that *haven't* changed. Any suggestions to fix this?

`Makefile`

```
foo.baz: foo.bar
  echo hello
```

When the contents of `foo.bar` do not change, rerunning `make foo.baz` still results in `hello` to be echoed onto the screen.

Comment: Are the Makefiles generated by CMake?

Comment: @squareskittles It appears to be `GNU Make 4.1`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: And it will always be executed, since the rule itself does not create `foo.baz` file which it declares to do.

Comment: @raspy Sorry, my bad, that was just for the example. I do indeed create the file in my actual Makefile. However, now that you say it, I should probably double-check that the file is getting created!